# Python Tkinter canvas rectangle with an image

Tags: python, image, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Hello I would like to know how can I fill a canvas.rectangle with an image but not a colour.

This is my codes :

```
 def P1():

 def square():
    x1,y1,x2,y2=0,675,75,750
    for i in range(0,10):
         for f in range(0,10):
            can1.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,fill="blue")
            x1=x1+75
            x2=x2+75
            list.append((x1,x2,y1,y2))
         x1,x2=0,75
         y1=y1-75
         y2=y2-75
         can1.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,fill="blue")
         list.append((x1,x2,y1,y2))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace the fill with something like fillImage because it doe not exists.
you should create a new canvas in you existing one with this.

```
photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = './test.gif')

canvas.create_image(0,0, image=photo)
```

Comment: did you mean "create a new image" rather than "create a new canvas"?

Comment: Thanks, it's working ,I would like to know if It's possible to do something like this but using the create.image : http://www.noelshack.com/2016-20-1463922731-sans-titre.png.