# Image on canvas widget Tkinter

Tags: python, image, canvas, tkinter

I already am almost finished with a game I am making, but now I want to have the characters that are moving around, look a bit better graphically than just blocks. However, all code has been made so, that it only works with canvas widgets (in this case rectangles) and not with images. 
So, is there a way to paste images onto such canvas widgets or fill canvas widgets with an image. After some research, I thought I could do this with PIL, but it didn't work for me.

Any tips or other recommended packages to use in this case? Or should I just rewrite all of my code to work with the image object (a.k.a. the things I asked about above are impossible).

Comment: Could you show your code? It's very hard to answer your question without seeing it.

Comment: Have you read through the documentation of the canvas widget? The methods for drawing images are documented there.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I know how to make an image on a canvas. But I want to have this image in a rectangle or any such shape.

Comment: Have you tried simply drawing a rectangle around the image?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the example [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/drawing/)?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
ZetCode Tkinter tutorial

In this script, we draw an image
on the canvas.

Author: Jan Bodnar
Last modified: July 2017
Website: www.zetcode.com
"""

from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, BOTH, NW
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()   

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.master.title("High Tatras")        
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.img = Image.open("tatras.jpg")
        self.tatras = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)

        canvas = Canvas(self, width=self.img.size[0]+20, 
           height=self.img.size[1]+20)
        canvas.create_image(10, 10, anchor=NW, image=self.tatras)
        canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


def main():

    root = Tk()
    ex = Example()
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What I want to do is to have an image in or on top of a shape in a canvas widget. So that I don't have to change any of my code.
(The image will thus act as a fill for a rectangle for example)

Comment: I don't think thats possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373820/python-tkinter-canvas-rectangle-with-an-image